# Error handling touch on View Android

Tags: android, android-view

I draw a menu picture by using Bitmap, and it didn't work when I tried to use TouchEvent to load another Activity in my MenuLoading Activity.

Could anyone fix the problem please? Thank you in advanced.

Here's the code I've used:

MenuView:

```
public class MenuView extends View{
    private Bitmap menu;
    boolean result = false;

    public MenuView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        menu = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.menu2);
  }
  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      canvas.drawBitmap(menu, 0, 0, null);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
      switch (ev.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
          // Code on finger down
          float posX = ev.getX();
          float posY = ev.getY();
          float x1 = 296, x2 = 528, y1 = 246, y2 = 304;
          if ((posX >= x1 && posX <= x2) && (posY >= y1 && posY <= y2)) {
              // we are in the square
              result = true;
          }
          else {
              // we are somewhere else
          }
          break;
      }
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
          // Code on finger up
          break;
      }
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
          // Code on finger move
          break;
      }
      }
      invalidate();
      return result;
  }
}
```

and MenuLoading Activity:

```
public class MenuLoading extends Activity {
    MenuView View;
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            View = new MenuView(this);
            setContentView(View);
            if (View.result == true){
                Intent i = new Intent (this, GameLoading.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: what's the error ? post the logcat please or explain what "didn't work" means please. + Put a Log to print posX and posY

Comment: When I click on the menu, It doesn't change to my other activity...

Comment: Strange, it doesn't print anything... I'm doomed...

Comment: Do yourself a favour.  Use recommended naming practices, or at least, don't use initial capitals in identifier names and don't use existing class names as identifiers.  `MenuView View;` ==> `MenuView menuView`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It make no sense to put this code in the `onCreate` :

```
if (View.result == true){
            Intent i = new Intent (this, GameLoading.class);
            startActivity(i);
}
```

Move it in the event handler:

```
// we are in the square
Intent i = new Intent (getContext(), GameLoading.class);
((Activity)getContext()).startActivity(i);
return true;
```

Comment: When I move it to the event handler in MenuView, it says startActivity(i) method is unidentified...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but the problem is still here, I couldn't link the activity with TouchEvent. Do you think there's problem with using Bitmap for drawing picture as a menu?

Comment: what means "I couldn't link the activity with TouchEvent" ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean, when I touch a point within the collision, there's nothing happen, and The picture I created as the menu stays still...

Comment: Put a Log to print posX and posY and/or put a breakpoint in `onTouchEvent` to see what's going on. (I think your problem is now the detection of the touched area : another way to diagnostic it is to remove the test `if ((posX >= x1 && posX <= x2) && (posY >= y1 && posY <= y2))` and see what's going on.